# Is is possible to resize(length) the slider extender control? And show rail track on the or below control?

Tags: html, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I used the ajax's slider extender control in my web page. I want to reduce the length of the control. 
How should i show the rail track on the control or below the control depending on the steps of the control?
How should i set length of the control?

If it is possible then provide some document related on this topic.

I used the control in following way...

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPercentageCompleted" runat="server" Text="0" Width="100%"  style="display:none;" 
         ontextchanged="txtPercentageCompleted_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
         <ajaxToolkit:SliderExtender ID="SliderExtender1" runat="server" BehaviorID="txtPercentageCompleted"
            TargetControlID="txtPercentageCompleted"
            Minimum="0"
            Maximum="100"
            BoundControlID="lblPercentage"
            Steps="5" EnableHandleAnimation="true">
         </ajaxToolkit:SliderExtender>
<asp:Label ID="lblPercentage" runat="server" Text="Label" Width="100%"></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved one of above issue that is **Setting size of the rail track of slider extender contrl**-

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPercentageCompleted" runat="server" Text="0" Width="100%"  style="display:none;" 
         ontextchanged="txtPercentageCompleted_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
         <ajaxToolkit:SliderExtender ID="SliderExtender1" runat="server" BehaviorID="txtPercentageCompleted"
            TargetControlID="txtPercentageCompleted"
            Minimum="0"
            Maximum="100"
            BoundControlID="lblPercentage"
            Steps="5" EnableHandleAnimation="true"
           RailCssClass="sliderrail"
            Orientation = "Horizontal">
         </ajaxToolkit:SliderExtender>
        <span style="float:left;width:8%;text-align:right;"> <asp:Label ID="lblPercentage" runat="server" Text="Label" Width="100%"></asp:Label></span>
```

Css of the sliderrail is-

```
.sliderrail
{
   position:relative;
   background-image:url('../images/slider_h_rail.gif');
   height:22px;
   width:100px;
}
```

Also there is `Length` property present to the slider control. By using we can set width/height of control and is depend on the `orientation` property that is `horizontal or vertical.`

Answer (score 0):

You could try to contain the control within a div with a width.

Or

You could view the output html that is produced and attempt to create css to limit the length. That is if you can create a selector based on any client Ids or similar.